# Как переопределить метод toString в собственной реализации TreeMap?

Tags: java, коллекции, методы

Есть реализованный `TreeMap` и в нем переопределен метод `toString ()`, но хотелось бы, чтобы сама реализация этого метода была более адекватная. Как возможно переопределить метод с помощью `StringBuilder` например?

```
public class MyTreeMap<K extends Comparable<K>, V> implements Set<K, V> {

private Node<K, V> root;
private int size;

public MyTreeMap() {
    root = null;
    size = 0;
}

@Override
public boolean containsKey(K key) {
    if (root == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return root.findKey(key);
}

@Override
public boolean containsValue(V value) {
    if (root == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return root.findValue(value);
}

@Override
public V get(K key) {
    if (root == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return root.getValue(key);
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
}

@Override
public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node<>(key, value);
        size = 1;
        return null;
    }
    V oldValue = root.putNode(key, value);
    if (oldValue == null) {
        size += 1;
    }
    return oldValue;
}

@Override
public V remove(K key) {
    if (root == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return root.removeNode(key);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return size;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    if (root == null) {
        return "No list";
    }
    return root.toString();
}

private class Node<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> {

    private Key k;
    private Value v;
    private Node<Key, Value> parent;
    private Node<Key, Value> left;
    private Node<Key, Value> right;


    public Node(Key k, Value v) {
        this.k = k;
        this.v = v;

        parent = null;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }

    public Node(Key k, Value v, Node<Key, Value> parent) {
        this.k = k;
        this.v = v;

        this.parent = parent;
        left = null;
        right = null;
    }

    public boolean findKey(Key k) {
        if (k.compareTo(this.k) == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        if (left != null && k.compareTo(this.k) < 0) {
            return left.findKey(k);
        }
        if (right != null) {
            return right.findKey(k);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean findValue(Value v) {
        if (v.equals(this.v)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (left != null && left.findValue(v)) {
            return true;
        }
        return right != null && right.findValue(v);
    }

    public Value getValue(Key k) {
        if (k.compareTo(this.k) == 0) {
            return this.v;
        }
        if (left != null && k.compareTo(this.k) < 0) {
            return left.getValue(k);
        }
        if (right != null) {
            return right.getValue(k);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Value putNode(Key k, Value v) {
        if (k.compareTo(this.k) == 0) {
            Value oldValue = this.v;
            this.v = v;
            return oldValue;
        }
        if (k.compareTo(this.k) < 0) {
            if (left != null) {
                return left.putNode(k, v);
            }
            left = new Node<>(k, v, this);
            return null;
        }
        if (right != null) {
            return right.putNode(k, v);
        }
        right = new Node<>(k, v, this);
        return null;
    }

    public Value removeNode(Key k) {
        if (k.compareTo(this.k) == 0) {
            if (left == null && right == null) {
                if (parent == null) {
                    removeRoot();
                } else {
                    parent.removeMe(this);
                }
            } else if (left != null && right == null) {
                if (parent == null) {
                    removeRoot(left);
                } else {
                    parent.removeMe(this, left);
                }
            } else if (left == null) {
                if (parent == null) {
                    removeRoot(right);
                } else {
                    parent.removeMe(this, right);
                }
            } else {
                Node<Key, Value> replacement = right.findNextNode();
                replacement.setLeft(left);
                if (parent == null) {
                    removeRoot(replacement);
                } else {
                    parent.removeMe(this, replacement);
                }
            }
            return v;
        }
        if (left != null && k.compareTo(this.k) < 0) {
            return left.removeNode(k);
        }
        if (right != null) {
            return right.removeNode(k);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void removeMe(Node<Key, Value> node) {
        if (node == left) {
            left = null;
        } else {
            right = null;
        }
    }

    private void removeRoot() {
        root = null;
    }

    private void removeMe(Node<Key, Value> node, Node<Key, Value> replacement) {
        if (node == left) {
            left = replacement;
        } else {
            right = replacement;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void removeRoot(Node<Key, Value> replacement) {
        root = (MyTreeMap<K, V>.Node<K, V>) replacement;
    }

    private Node<Key, Value> findNextNode() {
        if (left == null) {
            return this;
        }
        return left.findNextNode();
    }

    public void setLeft(Node<Key, Value> left) {
        this.left = left;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return k + "->" + v + (left != null ? " (" + left.toString() + ")" : " ()")
                + (right != null ? " (" + right.toString() + ")" : " ()");
    }
}
}
```

Добавление элементов в MyTreeMap:

```
 MyTreeMap<Integer, String> treeMap = new MyTreeMap<>();
    treeMap.put(15, "England");
    treeMap.put(12, "Poland");
    treeMap.put(18, "USA");
    treeMap.put(45, "Ukraine");
    treeMap.put(1, "Germany");
    treeMap.put(78, "Russia");
    treeMap.put(3, "Sweden");
    treeMap.put(80, "Italy");
    treeMap.put(27, "Brazil");
    treeMap.put(90, "Turkey");
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
15->England (12->Poland (1->Germany () (3->Sweden () ())) ()) (18->USA () (45->Ukraine (27->Brazil () ()) (78->Russia () (80->Italy () (90->Turkey () ())))))
```

Это мне подсказали, но я считаю это не самое лучшее решение((

Comment: Создать свой класс, унаследоваться от данного `TreeMap` (если это Ваш класс то этого делать не надо). Ну и изменить метод. Написать как Вам нужно.

Comment: Да, это мой класс и метод я переопределил, просто хочу более адекватный вывод информации на консоль, не такой как у меня на данный момент.

Comment: В таком случае уточните, что значит "более адекватный вывод".

Comment: Добавил в основной код в вопросе

Comment: @Inguarus а чем Вас этот не устраивает? вполне себе адекватный вывод

Comment: Напишите какой-нибудь обход дерева (обычно юзают inorder()) и перепишите toString() с его использованием.